# How do I implement Python's mock ANY in Golang

Tags: dictionary, go, match, fuzzy

I want to be able to compare two dictionaries while ignoring the value of some fields. This is extremely easy in Python with `mock.ANY`.

```py
from unittest.mock import ANY
actual = {'userName':'bob', 'lastModified':'2012-01-01'}
expected = {'userName':'bob', 'lastModified': ANY}
assert actual == expected
```

Here's my attempt in Go that leverages `cmp` which allows you to implement a `Equal` method (https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp#Equal) but it doesn't work. I believe it's because my `MatchAll` struct is not "assignable" to string. Is there anyway to get around this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp"
)

type MatchAll string

func (m MatchAll) Equal(v string) bool {
    return true
}

func main() { 
    matchAll := MatchAll("bruh")
    actual := map[string]any{
        "key": matchAll,
    }

    expected := map[string]any{
        "key": "foobar",
    }

    fmt.Println(cmp.Equal(expected, actual))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `cmp` code, I believe the problem here is that when comparing map elements, the type that's used to check for the existence of the `Equal` method is the element type of the map (here, `any`), not the concrete type of one of the two values (here, `string` or `MatchAll`). Since the `any` type does not declare an `Equal` method, it falls back to the built-in comparisons.

As an alternative, you could potentially use the [cmp.FilterValues](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp#FilterValues) and [cmp.Comparer](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp#Comparer) functions to construct an option that supports your special "equal-to-anything" value. For example, this would appear to work as intended:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp"
)

type matchAllType struct{}

var matchAll = matchAllType{}

var matchAllOption = cmp.FilterValues(
    // Filter function: returns `true` only for values using this comparison.
    func(x, y any) bool {
        return x == matchAll || y == matchAll
    },
    // Comparison function: called for pairs of values the filter accepts.
    cmp.Comparer(func(x, y any) bool { return true }),
)

func main() {
    actual := map[string]any{
        "key": matchAll,
    }

    expected := map[string]any{
        "key": "foobar",
    }

    fmt.Println(cmp.Equal(expected, actual, matchAllOption))
}
```

The always-true comparison function could possibly be replaced with [cmp.Ignore()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp#Ignore) as well, though I'm not entirely sure whether the semantics are exactly the same. It does work in the above example, at least.

There is also the [cmpopts.IgnoreMapEntries](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-cmp@v0.5.9/cmp/cmpopts#IgnoreMapEntries) option, which could be used as follows, but with slightly different semantics:

```
var matchAllOption = cmpopts.IgnoreMapEntries(func(_, v any) bool { return v == matchAll })
```

The difference is that with this option, the comparison would be `true` even if the `actual` dictionary did not contain an entry with a matching key at all, because the built-in map comparison tests whether "recursively calling Equal on *all non-ignored map entries* report equal", emphasis added. By contrast, the earlier solutions still require the other map to contain *some* value with the same key.

Comment: Thank you! I resorted to getting a slice of the diff between two maps and filtering out any diff that included `MatchAll` but this is far cleaner.

Comment: I found an issue. This solution doesn't work for lists: https://go.dev/play/p/donZxfGlH1C  I will post if I figure out a fix.

Comment: Not the most robust solution but I can fix this by extending the filter function

Comment: I imagine that's because `cmp` won't even try to make an element-by-element comparison between a `[]string` and an `[]any`. It does work when `actual` is also an `[]any`: https://go.dev/play/p/dl3gQp5pDyp